# getting data from database not working

Tags: php, database, arrays

This is my code. I think the problem is with `$retrieve["'choice'.'$i'"];` what is the correct format here?

```
$i = '1';
do {
   $choice[$i] = $retrieve["'choice'.'$i'"];
   $i++;
} 
while ($i <= $numberofchoices);
echo $choice['1']; //not working!!
```

Comment: To get an idea why, `echo "'choice'.'$i'";`  Remove those outer double-quotes and the quotes around the var.  `$retrieve['choice' . $i]` or interpolated in double quotes `$retrieve["choice$i"]`

Comment: `var_dump($choice)` before the while loop to see what's in it.

Comment: thanks guys. $retrieve['choice' . $i] or interpolated in double quotes $retrieve["choice$i"] works. credit to  Michael Berkowski. i echoed "'choice'.'$i'"; what i had previously and could see why it didnt work.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$i = '1';
do {
   $choice[$i] = $retrieve["choice".$i];
   $i++;
} 
while ($i <= $numberofchoices);
echo $choice['1'];
```

Comment: It may look cleaner as `$i = 1;`, but incrementing a number in a string works too